# How to convert given coordinates to KAZE Keypoints in Python with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, matching, descriptor

I try to compare two points in two different images, so I want to convert the coordinates to Keypoints to compute with them the description and matching results later.

I found the method:

```
 keypoint = cv2.KeyPoint(x, y, 0)
 vec = [keypoint]
```

and it works but as result I get everytime:

```
 >>>akaze.compute(image, vec)
 ([], None)
```

Even when I take detected keypoints, convert them to coordinates and back to keypoints (using the structure above) I get the same result.

So, how can I convert the given coordinates to keypoints (for example KAZE keypoints)?
Thank you a lot!

Regards,
Leo

Comment: IN C++ you can use [KeyPoint::convert](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html#ab6a67a0ab17d65a1b28502eba424bfde). There should be also the Python binding to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue that you created keypoint with **zero** size. According to [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html#gsc.tab=0), `KeyPoint` constructor signature requires 3 parameters: *x* and *y* coordinates and *size* (which is keypoint diameter). You set this *size* to zero.

Thus the first change is setting keypoint diameter, i. e. I supposed that this should work:

`keypoint = cv2.KeyPoint(x, y, 5)`

but it does not. The reason is that **OpenCV** keypoint descriptor computer doesn't accept keypoints with default *class_id* (**-1**). Really I don't know what is actual **class_id** purpose (see [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981126/what-is-the-meaning-and-use-of-class-member-class-id-of-class-cvkeypoint-in-op)), but I changed it to zero just because `akaze.detect(...)` method returns number of keypoint in this field (i. e. *0* for 1st keypoint, *1* for second one and so on). I also set *size* value to **5** because of the same reason - these values in detected points were from about **4.8** to **5.7**.

After these modifications everything became OK, i. e. this code:

```
keypoints = [cv2.KeyPoint(x, y, 5, _class_id=0)]
akaze = cv2.AKAZE_create("AKAZE")
akaze.compute(image, keypoints)
```

gave proper result in my case (**OpenCV 3.0.0**). I suppose that for **2.4.x** version it will be also OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked fine! That helped me a lot.